# Build array keys dynamically from another array

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to achieve the following? I.e. building the array keys from another array dynamically?

```
$array = (
    'key1',
    'key2',
    'key3'
);

Resulting in:: $arr['key1']['key2']['key3'] = array()/value;
```

So in other words the more values you add to $array (and or less) then the corresponding mulitidensional array is built up.

Thanks

Comment: What happened to `first` and `second`.  What do you mean `= true`?

Comment: I've edited my question - good point :)

Comment: Better but, what does `= array()/value;` mean?

Comment: your edited question makes no sense. You're asking about building an array off another, but only show a single array, then at the end of your question you talk about multidimensional arrays, which wasn't even a thing at the start of your question =)

Comment: All he needs is an array with keys that represent the values of another array. My question would be why? Explain more, maybe things can be done in a different way.

Comment: The reason is because I'm trying to build a tree of array values so each key is added onto the parent. I don't mind what array()/value is - that is there as an example. I will be adding that value myself. The multidimensional bit was there at the beginning and by having all the keys that is what you would be building. I am also working on a solution at the moment unless there is a really obvious way I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily build a recursive function, or I use a reference:

```
$array = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');

$result = array();
$temp = &$result;

foreach($array as $key) {
    $temp =& $temp[$key];
}
$temp = 'value'; //or whatever

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: That is what I'm after thank you :o) I haven't seen the ampersand used before in that way. What is that doing?

Comment: A [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Interesting - used it in passing before but never like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd already started, so I'll post my answer even though there's already an accepted answer:

```
$input = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
$result = array();

buildArray($input, $result);
print_r($result);

function buildArray($input, &$result){
    if(0 == count($input))
        return $result;

    $next = array_shift($input);
    $result[$next] = array();
    buildArray($input, $result[$next]);
}
```

Works, though I think the answer posted by @AbraCadaver is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time on it though :o)